# Running the Python API of Salome

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the meshing software Salome with Python. As i want to use a solely automated script for meshing of a simple geometry, i need the salome API.

Salome is so far installes on a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. and is running. However if i try to use one of the tutorial scripts in vscode i am only presented with:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'salome'

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately i wasn't able to resolve this problem and another task came along. I can't seem to find the right interpreter also using `source env_launch.sh` didn't help either. I can launch vscode in the right envorment after launching it from the salome program, but that is hardly, what i want to achieve as the main goal is to use python in a programm to create geometries meshes with salome without having to open salome. Opening should unly be neccessary to inspect the geometries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The problem is the following: I have installed salome on my ubuntu system. Salome has an API for python. All examples from the salome documentation start with importing salome to the code. Nothing special. However running the code fails since there is no module named salome. I need to run the code in the right enviroment. I fail to get the right enviroment and therefore can use the API. A solution i found online, to use the command `source env_launch.sh` doesn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be resolved by opening the terminal navigating to the salome directory and running the command

```
source env_launch.sh
```

immediately after that start VScode with

```
code
```

VScode now can import the salome packages and execute programms. This works for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the correct interpreter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`)
- Executes the code with the Python extension (`Run Python File`).

  [image]

Comment: Do you know where the python interpreter of salome i slocated? So far i have only access to the pre installed python interpreter in usr/bin/python3.10

Comment: You can check the installation information with the `pip show packagename` command. You can also use `full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install packege` to install packages for the current environment.